# Векторный поиск элемента в значении - списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация

Как получить список планет по критериям отбора?

`DataFrame.isin` для поиска значения в списке как здесь не подходит.
Очень желательно векторный способ Panadas, потому что тесты на большой базе данных.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Earth', 'Jupiter', 'Mars'],
    'mass_to_earth': [1.0, 317.8, 0.1],
    'kind': ['planet', 'planet', 'planet'],
    'colors': [['red','blue', 'green'], ['blue', 'green'], ['red','blue']]
})

print(df)

choice = df['name'][
    (df['mass_to_earth'] > 0.2) &
    (df['kind'].str.contains('planet', case=True, regex=False, na=False)) &
    (df['colors'].isin(['green'])) #это не работает как итератор
].tolist()

print(type(choice),choice)
```

И как вариант поиск в set пожалуйста для теста скорости:

```
'colors': [{'red','blue', 'green'}, {'blue', 'green'}, {'red','blue'}]
```

Comment: Интересно, каким образом из 8 (до 2006 года 9) планет получилась *большая* база данных? А если у вас все же достаточно много данных, то может лучше для них использовать что-то типа SQLite и применять SQL для выборок из нее

Comment: Мне сейчас нужно расширить Ваши познания в астрономии? ) Бодрящая новость перед сном - планет гораздо больше чем 8. И даже чем 9.
SQL да, позже попробую. А пока в рамках вопроса.

Comment: "И как вариант поиск в set" - у вас там в коде не **множества** (фигурные скобки), а **кортежи** (круглые скобки). В **множествах** реально поиск обычно быстрее, чем в **списках**, а вот в **кортежах**, скорее всего, от поиска в списках скорость не отличается.

Comment: Да, спасибо, тестируемые данные я сразу подготовил в set(), тут опечатка. поправлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['colors'].isin(['green']) # ошибка
```

Вот такой вариант условия нормально работает:

```
df['colors'].apply(lambda x: 'green' in x)
```

Вам по сути нужен `contains` для списков/множеств, его можно с помощью `lambda` так вот сделать.

Comment: Отлично, это быстрее на 10% чем вариант MaxU с нативным питон - циклом, и синтаксис гораздо "пандее" ), принимаю ответ, спасибо!

Comment: @GreenX5 А делать из `colors` множества вместо списков пробовали? Если не сделали, попробуйте, как MaxU советовал через `.map(set)`, возможно ещё быстрее станет. )

Comment: Да, конечно, сразу перевел в set колонку данных. Вероятно это уже упор в данной задаче, теперь дело за справочником категоризатором текста, сегодня буду исследовать. )

Answer (score 5):

**Вариант 1** - преобразовать список в CSV строку и искать при помощи регулярного выражения:

```
In [169]: df.loc[df["colors"].str.join(sep="|").str.contains(r"\bgreen\b")]
Out[169]:
      name  mass_to_earth    kind              colors
0    Earth            1.0  planet  [red, blue, green]
1  Jupiter          317.8  planet       [blue, green]
```

---

PS В микроязыке RegEx `\b` обозначает границу слова

**Вариант 2**: сначала преобразуем списки в множества (операция "element in set" - имеет асимптотическую сложность `O(1)`, а для списков это `O(n)`), потом поиск "в лоб":

```
df["colors"] = df["colors"].map(set)

In [176]: df.loc[["green" in x for x in df["colors"]]]
Out[176]:
      name  mass_to_earth    kind              colors
0    Earth            1.0  planet  {red, green, blue}
1  Jupiter          317.8  planet       {green, blue}
```

PS на первый взгляд этот вариант может показаться медленным из-за использования цикла, но на практике, такой вариант часто оказывается быстрее остальных для строковых типов данных. Нужно тестировать и сравнивать время выполнения на реальных данных...

Comment: Ой нет, спасибо, я как раз ищу альтернативу  str.contains более быструю, затем и разбил строку в список ). А еще интересно разбить на set, возможно поиск по кэшам еще быстрее окажется.

Comment: Большое спасибо за вариант 2, поиск в цикле по set оказался в 3 раза быстрее чем str.contains по строке на большом dataframe (я его просто создам изначально уже c set колонкой). Немного странно, что нет готового векторного метода поиска в set в Pandas....

Comment: @GreenX5, в этом нет ничего странного - Pandas предназначен для работы с табличными данными. В каждой ячейке таблицы предполагается использование __скалярных__ значений, а не списков или множеств)

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку имела значение еще и скорость выполнения, была подобрана самая подходящая функция - Series.map в паре с sets.issubset(), она на тестах отрабатывала стабильно повторяемо на 25-30% быстрее ближайшего конкурента Series.apply, итого:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Earth', 'Jupiter', 'Mars'],
    'mass_to_earth': [1.0, 317.8, 0.1],
    'kind': ['planet', 'planet', 'planet'],
    'colors': [{'red','blue', 'green'}, {'blue', 'green'}, {'red','blue'}] # set или frozenset 
})

print(df)

choice = df['name'][
    (df['mass_to_earth'] > 0.2) &
    (df['kind']=='planet') &
    (df['colors'].map({'green'}.issubset))
].tolist()

print(choice)
```

UPD:
Проверил, `df['colors'].apply({'green'}.issubset)` то же по скорости, вся фишка в `sets.issubset()`.

Оставляю принятым ответ CrazyElf, как первый в Pandas style )

Comment: Ну, кстати, `{'green'}.issubset` - это вообще отлично. Я про пересечение множеств вроде думал, но что-то не догадался до такого красивого функционального варианта. Лично я `apply` и `lambda` не очень люблю, обычно это показатель того, что не удалось найти нормальное красивое решение и пришлось городить костыль. Так что я за то, чтобы отдать зелёную галочку вам. )

Comment: Я вчера заодно потестил lambda в Pandas не меняя исполняемой функции, роняет зараза скорость в 2 раза. Буду её избегать впредь в Pandas, нелюбовь у них видимо. Зеленую галочку не трону, мне сюда еще обращаться ))